# Finding all positive solutions to $\sqrt{x + 2\sqrt{x+\cdots + 2\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{3x}}}} = x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

> Find all positive real solutions $x$ to the equation
> $$\sqrt{x + 2\sqrt{x+\cdots + 2\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{3x}}}} = x$$ and prove the expression is well-defined.

The number of radicals is arbitrary. Clearly $x=3$ satisfies the equation for any number of radicals (as can be shown more formally by defining the sequence $x_0 = 3, x_n = \sqrt{x+2x_{n-1}}$ for $n\ge 1$ and observing that it equals $\sqrt{x_0 + 2\sqrt{x_0+\cdots + 2\sqrt{x_0+2\sqrt{3x_0}}}} = x_0$). But how would one show that the only solution to the original equation is $3$? That is, if there exists some positive number of radicals satisfying the equation, then $x=3$? I tried defining the same sequence assuming $x$ satisfies the original equation, but without making assumptions like $x > 1$, I'm not sure how to show $x_n$ converges (one way I thought of was to show it's bounded above and is monotone but I'm not sure about the details).

> To clarify, the expression for $x_n$ (in terms of $x_0$ without any simplification) has $n$ radicals.

Comment: $\frac{x^2-x}{2}=x$

Comment: @JohnDouma:  that doesn't work for a finite number of radicals as one of your $x$s has one less.

Comment: What does "The number of radicals is arbitrary" mean?  Does it mean that $x$ should solved as a function of $n$, where $n$ is the number of radicals?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have shown that $x=3$ works for any number of radicals you can argue that both sides are monotonic and the derivative of the left side is less than $1$, so if $x \gt 3$ the right will be greater and if $x \lt 3$ the left will be greater.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you can compute the derivative of the LHS? It seems very complicated to do, especially if you have an arbitrary number of radicals.